# canvasElement.getContext and context.drawImage wrong image sizes when taking snapshot of a video tag that have a getUserMedia Stream

Tags: canvas, webrtc, drawimage

Example : I have a webcam, that webcam output 648x480 (but it could be any webcam with any width and height)...

I have this code

```
<video id="precam" playsinline="true" muted autoplay ></video>
<canvas id="canvax" ></canvas><div onclick="wcanvasim();">CAPTURE</div>


<script>
    const videoPlayer = document.querySelector("#precam"); 
    const canvasElement = document.querySelector("#canvax");
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video:true, audio:false }).then(stream => videoPlayer.srcObject = stream).catch(error => {console.error(error);});
    function wcanvasim () { var context = canvasElement.getContext("2d"); context.drawImage(videoPlayer, 0, 0 ); }
</script>
```

if I try

```
function wcanvasim () { var context = canvasElement.getContext("2d"); context.drawImage(videoPlayer, 0, 0, 640, 480 ); }
```

still not the correct image size

why and how to fix this ?

This is the result I have; it takes only a small portion of the original image :(

[image]

But I want to exact image that I see in the video tag

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/gh-pages/src/content/getusermedia/canvas

it's now

```
function wcanvasim () { 
 canvasElement.width = videoPlayer.videoWidth; 
 canvasElement.height = videoPlayer.videoHeight;
 canvasElement.getContext("2d").drawImage(videoPlayer, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
}
```